# Java keep Strings larger of it's limit

Tags: java, string

I have to keep strings with 5-6 billions of letters, of course it too large for common java.lang.String. Is there any ways to do this? Maybe another datatypes or smth...

Comment: What is the nature of this string?  It it a large binary string or something like that?

Comment: That's a lot of letters. Do you need to act on the entire "string" at once?

Comment: @Tyler, Yes, i gonna keep image's src inside this. But String is enough only for 2-3 large images

Comment: Why are you using `String` for image data?  Why not a byte array?

Comment: All "gigantic" objects have, at their heart, an array.  It is the size of the array that is ultimately the limiting factor.  Depending on the JVM, the limit will likely be somewhere between 16M and 2B bytes, and it doesn't much matter if you get 2B bytes, 1B characters (String), 500M ints, 250M doubles.  If you need to store more, store it in the file system.

Comment: did i do my math right? that's 5.77GB of memory you will need?

Comment: If your're going to store an image, you should you a stream, like InputStream/OutputStream (depending on it's usage). There is also a java.sql.Blob, for supporting the Blob data type (used to store images on a DB)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, by clicking img miniature in my project, it being inserted to contenteditable div as full image with it's content inside `src` attribute. This is easiest way to store images right inside msg, why i chose this. But now i got this problem. Seems like i have to refuse of this approach and remake the system..

Comment: You should not permanently load more than a handful of images into your app.  Rather, you should use an image cache so that the most recently referenced images are immediately available and the rest will be loaded "on demand" from the backing store.  Depending on your specific Java environment there apt to be several options for this cache, or you can roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a file on disk. You can process using any of the built in IO facilities. Input/Output streams, File Channels, Memory Mapping, RandomAccessFile, etc.